# copy mysql database by copying data .frm and .ibd

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using `Xampp` on windows .. in `MySQL` data dir I tried to duplicate a database by copying/renaming it's folder which contain `.frm` and `.ibd` data .. this was working with me on the past .. but now the new database seems blank in `phpmyadmin` and 'some' of tables appear in `phpmyadmin` sidebar navigation .. what I'm missing ?

I no longer have a version of the original db ( it is convereted ) and I only have this data folder .. So I need to get this working!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended way to copy a database, nor is copying the folder a good means of back up. In the case of copying the folder to make a duplicate of the database, some of the metadata probably had the old database name and then the server got confused because of having two similar database names.

In particular, InnoDB doesn't handle well any file-level manipulation of the data directory, but it's discouraged for all storage types.

You can try to stop the MySQL server, rename the folder to the original name, and start the MySQL server again in an effort to rescue some of your data, but odds are not good. Sorry for the bad news. I suggest you restore from a backup; even if you're able to get your current version working again you may have some deeper corruption that you're not able to detect.

By the way, phpMyAdmin has the ability to duplicate a database directly from the "Operations" tab.